# Кто знает как с одного клика в Delphi 7 добавить несколько параметров в реестр ?

Tags: delphi

В общем пишу я тут прогу есть задача добавить несколько параметров с одного клика

вот исходник

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
reg:Tregistry;
begin
reg:=TRegistry.Create;    // 
reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;         // 
reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies', true);
reg.WriteInteger('NoDriveTypeAutoRun', 16895);
reg.CloseKey; // освободили ключ 
reg.Free;// Я так предпологаю что ключ закрыт и можно по новой залазить в реестр 
end;      //и добавлять ключ но не тут то было там какаето декларация ожидаеться
          // вылазиет такая ошибка 
         //Error] SAK.pas(41): Declaration expected but identifier 'reg' found
          //[Error] SAK.pas(49): '.' expected but ';' found
          //Fatal Error] sak.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'SAK.pas'

reg:=TRegistry.Create;
reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg.OpenKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom', true)
//reg.WriteInteger('AutoRun', 00000000);
reg.CloseKey;
reg.Free;
```

Подскажите как одним кликом добавить несколько ключей?

Comment: Я понял как это делаеться у меня получилось вот 
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
reg:Tregistry;
begin
reg:=TRegistry.Create;    // íà÷àëî
reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;         // êîðåíü
reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies', true);
reg.WriteInteger('NoDriveTypeAutoRun', 16895);
reg.CloseKey; // Çàêðûëè è îñâîáîäèëè è èä¸ì äàëüøå
;


reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg.OpenKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom', true);
reg.WriteInteger('AutoRun', 00000000);
reg.CloseKey;
reg.Free;



end;

end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку так. Если не сработает - очистить reg и создать заново через Create. Главная ошибка была в том, что Вы после end написали код, это уже не процедура была.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  reg:Tregistry;
begin
  reg:=TRegistry.Create;    // 
  reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;         // 
  reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies', true);
  reg.WriteInteger('NoDriveTypeAutoRun', 16895);
  reg.CloseKey;
// тут, по идее, можно обойтись без освобождения ключа, просто переоткрыть его.
  reg.OpenKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom', true)
  //reg.WriteInteger('AutoRun', 00000000);
  reg.CloseKey;
  reg.Free;
end;
```

Comment: reg.OpenKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom', true)
вот сдесь точка с запятой мою ошибку повтарил код не скомпилируется будет там ругаться на декларацию....

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ проблема вообще была в (;), спасибо за ответ дружище 0xFF ,,, у меня ночью было озарение догадался до твоего ответа а догадался тогда когда написал комментарий к своему вопросу, там в комментарии и хотел сунуть исходник, но не вышло сделаю в ответе на свой вопрос ...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
reg:Tregistry;
begin
reg:=TRegistry.Create;    // начало
reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;         // корень
reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies', true);
reg.WriteInteger('NoDriveTypeAutoRun', 16895);
reg.CloseKey; // Закрыли и освободили и идём дальше
;

reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg.OpenKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom', true);
reg.WriteInteger('AutoRun', 00000000);
reg.CloseKey;
reg.Free;

end;

end.
```

Не думай я твой код не копировал 0xFF , просто догадался методом тыка и лёгким озарением спасибо!!! Извините что повторяюсь...

Comment: форматируйте текст. добавляйте отступы в коде. иначе таких ошибок будет очень много.

Comment: Понял спасибо за совет... У меня такая ошибка возникла при копировании исходного текста программы, видать точка с запятой не взялись. Дальше я хочу узнать как поймать исключение если параметр не добавляется из-за антивируса или фаеервола...